# How to draw many circles in pygame using shaders?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, shader, draw, cupy

I am relatively new to shaders and I was wondering how to draw many objects at once.

Here's the scenario: I am using Cupy to hold an array of circles with attributes of: x and y position and x and y velocity. I got the compute shader to work for the physics backend part, now I need to draw all of those circles onto a pygame window.

How would one go about this problem? How would I even start?

Thanks in advance!

What I Tried:
I can do it using the CPU power of pygame but it is very slow in using many circles.

```
def draw():
      window.fill((0, 0, 0))
      for i in range(ballsamount):
            x = float(balls[(i*4)//ballsamount][(i*4)%ballsamount])#indexes correct ball I promise!
            y = float(balls[(i*4)//ballsamount][(i*4)%ballsamount+1])
            pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), [x, y], 5)
      pygame.display.flip()
```

The problem is, it starts to get slow very quickly and the more I add, the slower it gets.
I know it is the drawing function that is slow because I commented it out and the framerate went through the roof.
`#draw()`
I am kind of stuck here. If anyone can tell me how to do this or even lead me to a video explaining how I would be forever grateful.

The entire script:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import*
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
pygame.init()

R = (800, 600)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(R)

ballsamount = 1000
balls = cp.random.random((4, ballsamount)).astype(cp.float32)

initballs = cp.RawKernel('''
      extern "C" __global__
      void init(float* ball){
            int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
            if (tid%4 == 0){
                  ball[tid] = ball[tid]*800.;
            }
            else if (tid%4 == 1){
                  ball[tid] = ball[tid]*600.;
            }
            else if (tid%4 == 2){
                  ball[tid] = 1.;
            }
            else if (tid%4 == 3){
                  ball[tid] = 0.;
            }
      }
''', 'init')

initballs((ballsamount,), (4,), (balls))

updateballs = cp.RawKernel('''
      extern "C" __global__
      void update(float* ball){
            int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
            if ((tid/2)%2 == 0){
                  ball[tid] = ball[tid] + ball[tid+2];
            }
      }
''', 'update')


def draw():
      window.fill((0, 0, 0))
      for i in range(ballsamount):
            x = float(balls[(i*4)//ballsamount][(i*4)%ballsamount])
            y = float(balls[(i*4)//ballsamount][(i*4)%ballsamount+1])
            pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), [x, y], 5)
      pygame.display.flip()

while True:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                  pygame.quit()
                  sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                  if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
      updateballs((ballsamount,), (4,), (balls))
      cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
      starttime = time.time()
      draw()
      print((time.time()-starttime))
```

Comment: `print()` in a hot loop will kill performance. Is it slow if you take that out?

Comment: Yes, I've taken it out, it's still slow and the difference is negligible, one print per loop isn't a performance-killing aspect because I'm not printing once for every ball but once per frame